# why the run button is not available to click it in android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

i have problem in android studio which is the run button is not available to me to click it (as you can see even when the emulator is open)

[image: 1]

any idea's?

Comment: You've to create a configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your dart sdk by going to File > Settings > Languages and Frameworks > Dart > Enable Dart Support then enter your Dart SDK Path and click OK

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Android Studio Settings > View > Appearance and click on the toolbar.

[image: Screenshot of settings]